# Numpy: Functional assignment?

Tags: numpy

Suppose I want to create an array `b` which is a version of array `a` with the `i`'th row set to zero.

Currently, I have to do:

```
b = a.copy()
b[i, :] = 0
```

Which is a bit annoying, because you can't do that in lambdas, and everything else in numpy is functional.  I'd like a function similar to theano's [set_subtensor](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html#theano.tensor.set_subtensor), where you could go

```
b = a.set_subtensor((i, slice(None)), 0)
```

or

```
b = np.set_subtensor(a, (i, slice(None)), 0)
```

As far as I can tell, there's nothing like that in numpy.  Or is there?

**Edit**

The answer appears to be no, there is no such function, you need to define one yourself.  See hpaulj's response.

Comment: Can you give a more complete example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142604/functional-assignment-in-numpy refer this as well.

Comment: That question has similar words in it but is about something different.

Comment: You could use `operator.setitem`: `operator.setitem(b, (i, slice(None)), 0) or b`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean a simple function like this:

```
def subtensor(a, ind, val):
    b=a.copy()
    b[ind] = val
    return b

In [192]: a=np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)

In [194]: subtensor(a,(1,slice(None)),0)
Out[194]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

Indexing takes a tuple like `(1, slice(None))`.

There are some alternative assignment functions like `put`, `place`, `copyto`, but none look like do this task.

These are equivalent:

```
b[0,:] = 1
b.__setitem__((0,slice(None)),1)
```

That is, the Python interpreter converts `[]` syntax into a method call.

This is an in-place operation.  I don't know of anything that first makes a copy.

Functions like `choose` and `where` return copies, but they (normally) work with boolean masks, not indexing tuples.